# Magento add to wishlist via ajax is not working with secure url (SSL installed)

Tags: magento

I am using magento add to wishlist via ajax
it's working fine but after install SSL on server and make secure magento checkout pages from admin.
It give me not any response from ajax (302 Found).

But if i open this url in new tab then it's working fine.
When i use https in request url then it gives me the following html response "Reload the page to get source for: REQUEST URL" and without https there is no response to display.

here below the code which i used for :-

```
function additemtowishlist(wId,pId)
{
    var wishlisturl = 'wishlist/index/ajaxadd/product/'+pId;
    var wishlistparam = '/?wishlist_id='+wId;
    var url = '<?php echo Mage::getUrl("",array('_secure'=>false))?>'+wishlisturl+wishlistparam;
    new Ajax.Request(url, {
        dataType: "json",
        onSuccess: function(response){
            if (typeof(response.responseText) == 'string') eval('data = ' + response.responseText); 
            if (typeof data.product_id != 'undefined') {
                var htmltoshow = '<div class="messages successmessage"><div class="success-msg"><span>'+data.message+'</div></div>';
                jQuery("#wishlistresulthome-"+data.product_id).html(htmltoshow);
                jQuery("#customwishlist-"+data.product_id).css('visibility','hidden');
            }
            else {
                 alert(Translator.translate('Error happened while creating wishlist. Please try again later'));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Simranjeet you may try this :-

```
function additemtowishlist(wId,pId)
{
    var wishlisturl = 'wishlist/index/ajaxadd/product/'+pId;
    var wishlistparam = '/?wishlist_id='+wId;
    var url = '<?php echo Mage::getUrl("",array('_secure'=>false))?>wishlist/index/ajaxadd/product/';
    new Ajax.Request(url, {
        method: 'post',
        parameters: {'wishlist_id':wId,'product_id':pId },
        onSuccess: function(response){
            if (typeof(response.responseText) == 'string') eval('data = ' + response.responseText); 
            if (typeof data.product_id != 'undefined') {
                var htmltoshow = '<div class="messages successmessage"><div class="success-msg"><span>'+data.message+'</div></div>';
                jQuery("#wishlistresulthome-"+data.product_id).html(htmltoshow);
                jQuery("#customwishlist-"+data.product_id).css('visibility','hidden');
            }
            else {
                 alert(Translator.translate('Error happened while creating wishlist. Please try again later'));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ravindra

it means i need to send paramaters in post not in querystring

thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that ajaxToCart has ssl functionality built into it, but if the theme developer was lazy they may have neglected to include the code that tells ajaxToCart that ssl is enabled. I found it in the following code from ajax_cart_super.js.

```
function ajaxToCart(url,data,mine) {
    var using_ssl = $jq('.using_ssl').attr('value');
    if(using_ssl==1) { 
        url = url.replace("http://", "https://");
    }
..
..
}
```

As you can see, ajaxToCart will replace the http with https, but only if there is an element with the class using_ssl and value=1.  The developer who made my theme didn't include that element, so when the ajax request points to an unsecure page that should be secure, the ajax response won't work in jquery.

So for me, the quick fix was to just add this element onto my pages.  I know this site will always have ssl enabled so I simply hard coded it into my template as shown below.

```
<input type="hidden" class="using_ssl" value="1" />
```

Once that was there, the javascript picked up the value and did the replacement.  So now it works fine for me by just adding that into the template.  If you are a theme developer and you want users to be able to switch this on and off, you may want to check against the settings in the admin.  Although you may be on an insecure page, it will tell you if ssl is enabled in the backend, which would require this fix to be added.

I haven't tested the following but I think it would look something like this...

```
if(Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()){
    echo '<input type="hidden" class="using_ssl" value="1" />';
}
```

BTW, after years of appreciating stackoverflow solutions, I am making my first post here.  Thanks to all contributors, the help is great and I'll try to pay it back now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try update your javascript url variable, by setting _secure to true value.

Comment: Thanks for reply,

But i have already used this then give me html response "Reload the page to get source for: REQUEST URL"

when i go Magento admin system->configuration->web in Secure tab base url with https than this problem occured but when i use http than it's working fine.
but https is must for me for make secure checkout pages

Comment: I had a similar situation, when I updated the content on the https pages from http with ajax. I resolved my problem by adding _secure value Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure()

Comment: where can i use this code 

Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure()

Comment: where is necessary to create a link with Mage::getUrl()

Answer (score 0):

please try with below with your wishlist url just change instead of my custom action

```
Mage::getUrl('',array('_secure'=>true))
```

I think that gets you the base secure url, I believe.

```
Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login',array('_secure'=>true))
```

Will get you to the login page. In other words,

```
Mage::getUrl('module/controller/action',array('_secure'=>true))
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply
But  i have already used this.

When i go Magento admin system->configuration->web in Secure tab base url with https than this problem occured but when i use http than it's working fine. but https is must for me for make secure checkout pages

Comment: have you try _secore = true ?

Comment: yes it give me nothing in response

i want to tell you that this problem occurred because of in admin i have pass with https url in  system->configuration->web in secure tab
if i am change this to http tha working fine

but https is must for me for make checkout pages secure

Comment: and if i open this request url in new tab than gives me right result
but i want result in ajax respone